# Load array of images in Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to load an array of images to canvas but don't know how to achieve it. I would appreciate it if I could get some pointers on how I can achieve it. I am using class-based component on React.

**My Code:**

```
drawCanvas(img, prevProps) {

const node = this.canvasRef.current;
const context = node.getContext("2d");


context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

// imgArray = [image1, image2, image3]

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

  const imageArray = Array.from(imgArray).map((image) => image)

  console.log(imageArray)
  
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = this.props.image;
  img.onload = () => this.drawCanvas(img, prevProps);
}
```

Comment: Define "loading an array of images to a canvas". That could mean a bunch of different things, but none are super obvious by default. Do you mean a slideshow that it changes through, stacking them all up and some are transparent, show them as thumbnails in a grid, etc.?

Comment: I want to layer them on top of each other.

Comment: So they're transparent and you'd see through each one?

Comment: Yep, they're transparent.

Comment: Do you already have the image objects, or just the sources to them?

Comment: I already have the image object stored in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of this really involves React at all, other than you need to get a hold of the canvas reference, which you're doing.

If you already have the array of image objects, it's actually pretty straightforward. Just call `drawImage()` for each image in the array. You'll probably want to clear before you start drawing them, so the last ones don't bleed through and create weirdness.

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
imageArray.forEach(image => {
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
});
```

And that's it. Pretty straightforward.